# Contar numeros repetidos en un array

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

Tengo un array que tendrá de forma aleatoria entre 500 y 1000 posiciones. Y en cada posición se guarda un valor que sera entre 1 y 50. Para conseguir este array he creado las siguientes funciones:

```js
//Funcion numero aleatorio entre 1 y 50
function generaAleatorio(min,max)
{
        return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}

//Funcion array de n posiciones(aleatoria) con valores entre 1 y 50 (aleatorias)

function generaNaleatorios(n,min,max)
{
   var arrayNaleatorios=new Array(n);
   var control=0;
   while(control<n)
   {
       arrayNaleatorios[control]=generaAleatorio(min,max);
       control++;
   }
   
    return arrayNaleatorios;
}
```

Hasta aquí mas menos bien. Ahora tengo que crear otra función que en la posición 0 del array tengo el número de repeticiones del 0, en la posición 1 las del número 1, en la posición 2 las repeticiones del 2.... Osea contar las veces que se repite un mismo numero dentro del array y guardarlo en otro. No se si me explico.
 ¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El siguiente algoritmo cuenta las ocurrencias de cada numero, este algoritmo es muy conocido por countSort(Ordenamiento por cuentas), el cual trata de:

en el que se cuenta el número de elementos de cada clase para luego ordenarlos. Sólo puede ser utilizado por tanto para ordenar elementos que sean contables

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6];
var indices = new Array(8); // colocar en vez de 8 el max del array "x"
indices.fill(0);

for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {

  for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
    if (i == x[j]) {
      indices[i] = indices[i] + 1;
    }
  }
}
console.log(indices);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta me sirvio:

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar un array asociativo, es decir, un array clave-valor en el cual cada una de las claves del array haría referencia a cada uno de los números diferentes de tu array.

Después, recorrer cada uno de los números del array mediante un bucle y sumarle, para cada uno de los números, el contador que tuvieran anteriormente (o 0 si no había aparecido aparecido ese número todavía) más uno. Al ser un array asociativo puedes saber cual es el contador que tenía cada número anteriormente debido a que la clave dentro del array `repetidos` va a ser igual al número en cuestión.

```js
var array = [4,1,2,1,1,3,45,13,42,52,45,25,13,40,13,2];

var repetidos = {};

array.forEach(function(numero){
  repetidos[numero] = (repetidos[numero] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(repetidos);
```

Comment: Me ha sido de utilidad el codigo de @Francisco Romero sin embargo tengo la siguiente duda: Luego de calculado el Json { "1": 3, "2": 2, "3": 1, "4": 1, "13": 3, "25": 1, "40": 1, "42": 1, "45": 2, "52": 1 } Cual es la opción adecuada para acceder solo a las secuencias de repetición para obtener un vector de esta forma: > 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 Es decir solo abstraer de la cadena los count de las repeticiones Gracias por su colaboración

Answer (score 0):

> Se presento el siguiente error "No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'. Ts (7053)"

Lo solucioné añadiendo la siguiente linea antes de la declaración "repetidos = {};"

```
var repetidos: { [x: string]: any; };
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es más sencilla que todo eso.

Supongamos que tenemos el array

```
ejemplo=new Array(3,28,3,4,5,3,5,7,5,4);
```

Lo ordenamos, pero utilizando y colocando previamente la función auxiliar "comparar" que es tan conocida por todos quienes programamos. Si no lo hacemos podría ordenarlo de forma alfanumérica, y nos interesa que sea en modo numérico.

```
function comparar(a, b){return a - b}
```

Y en el interior de otra función ordenamos el array "ejemplo".

```
ejemplo.sort(comparar)
```

El programa ordenaría el conjunto de manera invisible para nosotros de esta forma:

```
ejemplo.sort(comparar)=new Array(3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,7,28)
```

Esto, repito, lo hace el programa de manera invisible para nosotros.

Realizamos un bucle con 10 repeticiones. Ojo!!! justas las que corresponde al número de elementos. Si hacemos un número superior al de elementos no funcionará. Si ponemos 11 en vez de 10 nos aparecerá el clásico Undefined

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
if(ejemplo[i]==ejemplo[i-1]){variable1=ejemplo[i]}

textomuestra.innerHTML=variable1 (este identificador lo colocaríamos en el "body")
```

El identificador marcaría el último elemento repetido dos veces. Pero.... ¿Qué pasa si queremos que localice al que se repite tres veces?

Creamos otra variable sobre la marcha "variable2" y otro identificador que lo muestre para localizar y reflejar los que se repiten tres veces. La programación sería la siguiente:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
if(ejemplo[i]==ejemplo[i-2]){variable2=ejemplo[i]}
```

La lógica de esto es que si se repiten tres veces y la serie está ordenada pues la posición i será igual a la i-2, así como la intermedia i-1.

Para seleccionar los que se repiten cuatro veces pues pondríamos:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
if(ejemplo[i]==ejemplo[i-3]){variable3=ejemplo[i]}
```

Y así sucesivamente.