# Ayuda con número de veces que se repite un número

Tags: javascript, html

Hola gracias por venir necesito hacer un programa con "javascript" en el cual introduzca 10 números y luego me diga que números y cuantas veces se repitieron.
tengo hecho esto:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){  
numerosaux.push(Math.random()*10); 
numeros.push(parseInt(numerosaux[i], 10));       
}      
 //con eso genero los numeros
 for(var j=0;j<10;j++)    
 for(var i=0;i<10;i++){  
 if(frecuencia.includes(numeros[i])){  
  /*aca tengo el problema nose como ponerla cantidad de veces que  repitio 
  el numero */
 }else{  
frecuencia[j]=numeros[i];  
 }  
}
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar con eso? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Para que se te pueda ayudar debes anexar al menos una porción de código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: ¿Y que llevas hecho? ¿Que errores te marca? No podemos hacer todo el trabajo por ti.

Comment: Ok perdon es mi primera vez en este sitio y novato en la programación.

Comment: [En esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/116252/contar-numeros-repetidos-en-un-array) tienes la respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo con comentarios por si te es de utilidad:

```js
var numeros = [];

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){  
numeros.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);  
}      
//Lista de números del 1 al 10
console.log(numeros);

//Creo una función para poder ordenar por Sort
function sortNumber(a,b) {
  return a - b;
}

//Ejecuto el Sort para realizar el ordenamiento
numeros.sort(sortNumber);

//console.log(numeros);

//Ciclo donde se evalúa el si el número actual se encuentra dentro del array, en caso de ser así te aumenta +1 en count
    var numActual = null;
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        if (numeros[i] != numActual) {
            if (count > 0) {
                console.log("Número " +numActual+ " se repite: "+count+ " veces");
            }
            numActual = numeros[i];
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        console.log("Número " +numActual+ " se repite: "+count+ " veces");
    }
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias esto también me sirvió muchísimo.Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu duda podrías solucionarlo de esta forma.

```
var nums = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // Valores aleatorios de 0 a 2
  nums[randomNum] = (nums[randomNum] || 0) + 1; 
}
```

Después de asignar el número obtenido en en el índice correspondiente del array, se realizará la cuenta para saber cuantas veces aparece un número.

La primera vez `nums[randomNum]` será `undefined` porque no tiene ningún valor asignado y por lo tanto no se puede realizar la suma `undefined + 1`. Por ello se añade la condición `nums[randomNum] || 0` para asignar el valor de 0 si es la primera vez que aparece el número.

Si después haces un `console.log` de `nums` verás que obtienes el número de veces que ha aparecido un número. Puedes mostrarlo de la siguiente forma.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, 'se repite', nums[i], 'veces')
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me ha sido de gran ayuda saludos.