# Contar el numero de A de una palabra JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy empezando en programación y tengo el siguiente ejercicio:
Función que solicite una frase y diga en un `alert` cuantas "A" tiene usando un `for`.
He estado mirando por Internet y veo distintos códigos que no logro entender ni hacer que funcionen.

```
function contar () {
    var palabra = prompt ("Pon una palabra")
    for(var i=0; i<texto.length; i++){
        if (texto[i] == caracter){
            cont = cont + 1;
            console.log(cont);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No vas mal del todo. Pero fíjate que unas veces usas `palabra` y otras veces `texto` para guadar el valor introducido por el usuario. También te falta definir la variable `caracter` (podría ser un parámetro de la función, o podría ser una variable que inicializas en 'a'). Tampoco has inicializado `cont`.

Comment: También muy relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/116252/contar-numeros-repetidos-en-un-array

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar un "match" como este ejemplo

```
var contar = palabra.match(/a/g).length;
alert(contar);
```

Y saldrá una alerta indicando el numero de veces que aparece la letra "a".

Comment: En la pregunta menciona _"usando un for"_. Es posible que esto sea un requerimiento de no ser así esto sería una buena respuesta. Aun que también creo que en este caso la mejor ayuda es explicar los problemas de su código como ha hecho @ordago en el comentario.

Comment: Tienes razón, me he saltado el for sin darme cuenta, aun así dejare la respuesta por si sirve de ayuda a alguien, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

- Puedes hacer uso de `Array.from` para que se transforme el `string` en un vector cuyos elementos se pueden recorrer
- Una vez que la cadena de texto se transforma en vector recorres cada posición y verificas con `===` si el elemento en cada vuelta es igual a `A`
- Hacemos uso de `===` para verificar que el elemento sea igual en tipo y valor
- Ya para que se haga dinámico, solo basta que a la variable `palabra` la iguales con la función `prompt()` para leer y trabajar con el `string` que ingrese el usuario

Código

```js
    function contar() {
      let palabra = "AnacondaAltaA"
      let palabraFragmentada = Array.from(palabra)
      let contador = 0
      console.log(palabraFragmentada)
      for(i=0; i<palabraFragmentada.length; i++) {
        if(palabraFragmentada[i] === "A") {
          contador++
        }else{
        }
      }
      return contador
    }
    
    console.log(contar())
```

O bien puedes trabajar tu solución con el método `reduce()` el cual reduce un vector de valores y retorna un único valor:

```js
    let palabra = "AnacondaAnaA"
    
    let convertida = Array.from(palabra)
    let resultado = convertida.reduce((total = 0, elemento) => {
      if(elemento === "A") {
        total = total + 1
      }
      return total
    }, 0)
    console.log(resultado)
```

Y obtenemos como salida:

> 3

Comment: ¿No es un string recorrible en un bucle for por defecto? Creo que no te es necesario hacerte un Array de chars, ya que un string actúa como tal.

Comment: si @FernandoCarrascosa efectivamente lo es, solo fue un modo de proponer, pero igual tienes razón ya que sería un paso *de más*

Comment: vamos Aprendiz, esta respuesta no me parece buena, pense que ibas a hacer el [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) al convertirlo en array

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo.. la mas sencilla que se me ocurre es tomar el string y utilizar la funcion match() que te regresa la cantidad de 'a' en forma de arreglo... luego solo tienes que tomar la longitud del arreglo y tienes la cantidad de 'a'... como la respuesta anterior... pero si debes hacerlo con un for.. deberias cambiar lo siguiente en tu funcion..

```js
     function contar () {
        let caracter='a', cont =0;
        var palabra = prompt("Pon una palabra")
        for(var i=0; i<palabra.length; i++){
        if (palabra[i] == caracter){
            cont++
        }     
        }
        alert('la cantidad de a es: '+cont)
    }
    
    contar()
```

palabra es la variable donde se guarda lo que te insertan en el `prompt` caracter es la letra que deseas contar.. (vale decir que se diferenciaran mayusculas de minusculas.. si quieres contar las mayusculas debes hacer un toLowerString() de palabra[i])

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en lo que tienes hecho, y que dices claramente que debes usar un bucle `for`, te propongo la siguiente solución comentada y genérica (te valdría para cualquier letra).

He asumido que no necesitas diferenciar mayúsculas de minúsculas, si no es así, con quitar los .toLowerCase() sería suficiente.

```js
function contarLetra(letra) {

  // Pedimos al usuario una palabra. La pasamos a lowercase para no diferenciar mayúsculas de minúsculas
  const palabra = prompt ("Pon una palabra").toLowerCase();

  // Sacamos el comparador como el valor de letra en lowercase para no diferenciar mayúsculas de minúsculas
  const comparador = letra.toLowerCase();

  // inicializamos el valor del conteo a cero.
  let cont = 0;
  
  // Iteramos sobre los caracteres de la palabra introducida
  // let i=0; es el valor inicial del iterador
  // i < palabra.length; el valor del iterador no debe llegar a la longitud de la palabra
  // i += 1; añade al iterador 1 despues de cada iteración
  for(let i=0; i < palabra.length; i+=1) {
  
    // Si la letra que estamos evaluando es igual que comparador, añadimos 1 a cont.
    if( palabra[i] === comparador ) cont += 1;
  }

  // Devolvemos el valor de conteo
  return cont;
}


console.log(contarLetra('a'));
```