# como contar los números repetidos en un array con javascript

Tags: javascript

necesito que el codigo cuente los numeros repetidos en cada posicion del array, es decir array en posicion [0][1] es igual al array en posicion [0][2] y cuente las veces que se repite dicho numero.

```js
var array = [ ['1','1','2','2','6'],
              ['2','3','4','4','6'] ];

var repetidos = []

var cont = 0
for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        
        if (array[i][j] === array[i][j]) {
            cont++;
            
            if (cont>1) {
                console.log(array[i][j])
                repetidos.push(array[i][j])
               
                cont=0
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
console.log(repetidos)
```

Comment: Posible duplicado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/116252/contar-numeros-repetidos-en-un-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para simplificar mucho más tu código lo que podrías realizar es un array asociativo, es decir, un array clave-valor en el cual la clave va a ser cada uno de los números del array.

A continuación, como tu array es un array de arrays, crearemos dos bucles `forEach`, el primero para recorrer cada uno de los arrays contenidos y el segundo para recorrer cada uno de los valores de cada array.

Por último, para cada valor sumaremos el valor anterior que hayamos obtenido (o 0 si no ha salido previamente) más uno. Como es un array asociativo, podremos saber si ha salido previamente o no ya que si ha salido con anterioridad podremos hacer referencia a el en el array asociativo mediante su clave.

```js
var array = [ ['1','1','2','2','6'],
              ['2','3','4','4','6'] ];

var repetidos = {}

array.forEach(function(arrayContenido) {
    arrayContenido.forEach(function(valor) {
      repetidos[valor] = (repetidos[valor] || 0) + 1;
    });
});

console.log(repetidos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

1. Primero convierte la matriz de datos en un vector con el método `flat()`
2. Segundo usa el método `reduce()` para poder devolver un solo resultado del vector aplicando un operador ternario donde identifiques si el valor *actual* de la iteración es igual a un registro en específico, es decir *(cualquier número que tu desees)*
3. Si el registro actual coincide con el valor pasado en el operador ternario entonces a valor previo sumale 1
4. Si lo anterior se cumple entoncesw finalmente haz un retorno del valor previo
5. Para que la suma se pueda llevar a cabo entonces inicializa en 0 *aunque aquí lo puedes inicializar en el valor que desees*

Código

```
let numeros = [ ['1','1','2','2','6'],
              ['2','3','4','4','6'] ]

let vectorNumeros = numeros.flat()

let res = vectorNumeros.reduce((previo, actual) => {
  (actual === '2') ? previo = previo + 1 : 0
  return previo
}, 0)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: La operación `flat()` es costosa y destructiva, es mejor preservar la estrucutra original de los datos.

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza te agradezco el comentario, dejaré la respuesta por fines informativos, sin embargo te agradecería donde me pueda documentar mas al respecto de lo que mencionas. Saludos y gracias nuevamente